# Calendar Overlay in sharepoint2013 programatically

Tags: calculated-column

I want to create calendar overlay in sharepoint2013 programatically using visual studio2012.
Please help how to start with that.

Happy Sharepoint!!!

Regards,
Aisha.

Comment: Aisha, have you tried out of the box [Calendar Overlays as explained here](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/03/15/how-to-use-calendars-overlay-in-calendar-lists-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

Comment: I dont want out-of-box. i want programatically.

Comment: Hi Aisha,Have you found any solution to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

As exposed by @SWW13 in her/his the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28993105/programmatically-add-calendar-overlay-aggregation-to-sharepoint-calendar-using, here's the server-side C# code you can use:

```
SPView targetView = calendarList.Views["SampleView"];
String XML = "<AggregationCalendars>" +
                "<AggregationCalendar Id=\"{1873e3f2-1e8f-4c46-94fe-6aaf0bd89c1d}\" Type=\"SharePoint\" Name=\"Sample Aggregation\" Description=\"\" Color=\"5\" AlwaysShow=\"True\" CalendarUrl=\"/path/to/calendar/Sample Aggregation.aspx\">" +
                    "<Settings WebUrl=\"http://server/path/to/calendar\" ListId=\"{73ec9181-0bf1-4263-9387-905cc1ec6d38}\" ViewId=\"{814140ee-3291-45fb-b994-b6e22dbc8676}\" ListFormUrl=\"/path/to/calendar/DispForm.aspx\"/>" +
                "</AggregationCalendar>" +
            "</AggregationCalendars>";
targetView.CalendarSettings = XML;
targetView.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

The overlays are defined in [SPView.CalendarSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.calendarsettings.aspx) property, it is an XML file that generate the overlay information like this:

```
<AggregationCalendars>
    <AggregationCalendar Id="{26ddb82c-9e2b-4c5d-9b7e-4ee25cf5c357}" 
                         Type="SharePoint" 
                         Name="My Overlay Calendar" 
                         Description=""
                         Color="5" 
                         AlwaysShow="False"
                         CalendarUrl="/Lists/MyOverlayCalendar/calendar.aspx">
        <Settings WebUrl="http://demo" 
                  ListId="{428bd2cb-a32d-4867-b658-6498158636a8}" 
                  ViewId="{09928cd4-9a5e-44ed-9bf2-dfe1fc85661b}" 
                  ListFormUrl="/Lists/MyOverlayCalendar/DispForm.aspx" />
    </AggregationCalendar>
</AggregationCalendars>
```

Source: [Programmatically Setting Sharepoint 2010 Calendar Overlays](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2011/06/programmatically-setting-sharepoint-2010-calendar-overlays/)

PS: The article is for SharePoint 2010 but should work for SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Hi thanks for ur reply. But i want steps to workout. R else please provide me alternate method. thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi to all, I created List Instances through visual studio2012..now i can able to see the created list names in sharepoint2013. Now my scenario is how do i get the events for same date and time..which specified in three lists programatically integrate with calender overlay.